# Does [NSMutableDictionary setValue: value forKey: key] retain NSString key?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

When adding items to `NSMutableDictionary` using the `setValue:forKey:` method (I suppose this generalizes to any `NSObject`) does the dictionary retain the second parameter, the `NSString`?

For example:

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSString *theString = @"hello";
int i;
for (i=0; i<[theString length]; i++){
    NSNumber *myInt = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i];
    NSString *character = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C",[theString characterAtIndex:i]];
    [dict setValue: myInt forKey:character];
}
[dict release];
[pool release];
```

Clearly, there is no reason to release `myInt` in the loop, it is retained by `dict` so it can't be released until the end of the code. But is the same true of `character`? My thinking is that if `NSMutableDictionary` stores the string in some other way, then one could create a temporary pool around the loop and release those strings instead of waiting  until the release of the dictionary.

I am also curious as to why `retainCount` of `character` is 7fffffff as if it is an `NSConstantString`, I would expect `stringWithFormat` to return an `NSString` object which would need retaining, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Just a fine point that doesn't merit an answer: in code for 10.4 and later, it's usually preferable to use [pool drain] instead — when GC is on, drain provides a hint that it *might* be a good time to collect old references, whereas release becomes a no-op. With GC off, they function identically.

Comment: This is an old question but you probably meant to use `setObject:forKey:` instead. [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249634/wheres-the-difference-between-setobjectforkey-and-setvalueforkey-in-nsmutabl)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's very common in Cocoa for `NSString` parameters to be copied instead of retained. That's because you could have just as easily given the dictionary an instance of `NSMutableString`. Because the string's value could change, `NSDictionary` makes a copy.

But, regardless of how `NSMutableDictionary` really operates, you don't have to worry whether `character` needs to be retained. Once you've passed it to `NSMutableDictionary` as a parameter, it's really that class's problem to decide how to store the data, unless the documentation specifically tells you that retaining the objects are your responsibility.

I also wouldn't worry too much about the `retainCount` of any object. Following the retain count of an object too closely can lead you down rabbit holes that just make you spin your wheels.

Finally, I really don't think you need to create your own autorelease pool here. Unless you know with absolute certainty that `theString` is going to be very long, or you've already observed high memory utilization in Instruments, adding the autorelease pool is an unnecessary optimization.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to retain `character` there, the dictionary retains it when you set it as a key and your own code has no need to retain it.

You also don't need to worry about why the retain count isn't what you expect. Maybe the Foundation framework has Flyweight-like instances of a load of single-character `NSString` instances. In any case if you've got the memory management correct following the guidelines, you'll be OK regardless of what the framework's doing behind the scenes. http://iamleeg.blogspot.com/2008/12/cocoa-memory-management.html