# Where's the difference between setObject:forKey: and setValue:forKey: in NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: ios, iphone, nsmutabledictionary

When looking at the documentation, I hardly see any big difference. **Both "value" and "object" are of type id**, so can be any object. Key is once a string, and in the other case an id. One of them seems to retain the object, and the other don't. What else? Which one is for what case?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-C: What's the Difference between objectForKey and valueForKey?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062183/objective-c-whats-the-difference-between-objectforkey-and-valueforkey)

Answer (score 167):

`setValue:forKey:` is part of the [NSKeyValueCoding](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol, which among other things, lets you access object properties from the likes of Interface Builder. `setValue:forKey:` is implemented in classes other than `NSDictionary`.

`setObject:forKey:` is `NSMutableDictionary's` reason to exist. Its signature happens to be quite similar to setValue:forKey:, but is more generic (e.g. any key type). It's somewhat of a coincidence that the signatures are so similar.

What adds to the confusion is that NSMutableDictionary's implementation of `setValue:forKey:` is equivalent to `setObject:forKey:` in most cases. In other classes, `setValue:forKey:` changes member variables. In `NSMutableDictionary`, it changes dictionary entries, unless you prefix the key with a '@' character -- in which case it modifies member variables.

So, **in a nutshell, use `setObject:forKey:` when you need to work with dictionary keys and values, and `setValue:forKey:` in the rarer cases where you need to tackle [KVP](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html).**

EDIT: and oh, it looks like this has been asked and answered before: [Difference between objectForKey and valueForKey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062183/objective-c-whats-the-difference-between-objectforkey-and-valueforkey)

Comment: that question is not exactly the same. it is about the getter methods, whereas this question is about the setter methods

Comment: What do you mean by "In NSMutableDictionary, it changes dictionary entries, unless you prefix the key with a '@' character -- in which case it modifies member variables." What member variables? Also maybe you can comment on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755917/ ? Thanks.

Comment: just for completeness, setObject:forKey will raise (exception) if object is nil. Will setValue:forKey behave the same, or will it remove existing object from dictionary when setting nil for key?

Comment: Great answer. Really. for completeness though, it would be nice to mention that (on NSMutableDictionary at least) setValue:forKey: tolerates nil values, and removes the entry - while setObject:forKey: will throw exception and crash when handed nil values.

Comment: In general, I recommend to use the modern Objective-C Syntax with `NSMutableDictionary` which completely avoids the confusion:
`
NSMutableDictionary *myDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
myDict[myKey] = myValue;
`

Answer (score 86):

Another difference is that if you give a nil value to `setValue:forKey:`, it removes the key from the dictionary if it exists, otherwise does nothing. But if you give a nil value to `setObject:forKey:`, it raises an exception.

Comment: This is super useful to know. I had otherwise written my own category on NSMutableDictionary to accomplish exactly this!. Thanks

Comment: Another difference is with objective-c subscripting, you can write `dic[key] = value;` to support removing the key if value is `nil`. Subscripting is generally a better approach than `setValue:forKey:` to accomplish this.

Answer (score 11):

**`-setValue:forKey:`** just send `-setObject:forKey:` to the receiver, unless the value is `nil`, in which case send `-removeObjectForKey`.

Dead simple.

Comment: oh you're right, bro. Sorry about that. It's documented here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsmutabledictionary/1416335-setvalue?language=objc

Answer (score 4):

**anObject** — The value for key. The object receives a retain message before being added to the `NSDictionary`. This value must not be nil.

**aKey** — The key for value. The key is copied (using `copyWithZone:`; keys must conform to the `NSCopying` protocol). The key must not be nil.

**value** — The value for key.

**key** — The key for value. Note that when using key-value coding, the key must be a string (see “Key-Value Coding Fundamentals”).

Comment: Thanks for giving the atual reason why setObject:forKey:  raises an exception. @breakfreehg