# Why doesn't setValue:forKeyPath invoked on mutable dictionary throw exception for unknown keypaths?

Tags: objective-c, key-value-coding

I have following code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[defs setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:100] forKey:@"test1.test2.test3"];
[defs setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:10] forKeyPath:@"test2.test3.test4"];
```

I understand that `setObject:forKey:` creates association between "test1.test2.test3" key and given number object. On the other hand, `setValue:forKeyPath:` is Key-Value-Coding method that tries to locate object for path "test2.test3.test4", but in the end, it just silently does nothing. It doesn't even modify the dictionary!

What confuses me greatly is that `setValue:forKeyPath:` doesn't raise any exception nor does it report any error. Why is this? Is this behavior documented anywhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't find any documentation for this specific case, sorry, but my guess is that this:

```
[defs setValue:x forKeyPath:@"a.b.c"];
```

Is being implemented something like this:

```
[[defs objectForKey:@"a"] setValue:x forKeyPath:@"b.c"];
```

So `objectForKey:` returns `nil`, and methods called on `nil` just do nothing. That would explain the behaviour you have described.

Comment: Thanks. That would indeed explain the silence :-(

Answer (score -1):

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [@{@"test1" : [@{@"test2":[@{} mutableCopy]} mutableCopy]} mutableCopy];

[dict setValue:@(100) forKeyPath:@"test1.test2.test3"]; // ok
[dict setValue:@(200) forKeyPath:@"test1.test2.test4"]; // ok
[dict setValue:@(300) forKeyPath:@"test1.test21"];      // ok
[dict setValue:@(400) forKeyPath:@"test1.test22.test3"]; // fail, test22 not mutable

[dict setValue:[@{} mutableCopy] forKeyPath:@"test1.test23"]; // ok
[dict setValue:@(500) forKeyPath:@"test1.test23.test34"]; // ok
```

Comment: Please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to lift your content quality up