# iphone: What is the difference between setObject:forKey: and setValue:forKey: in Adding Entries to a Mutable Dictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where's the difference between setObject:forKey: and setValue:forKey: in NSMutableDictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249634/wheres-the-difference-between-setobjectforkey-and-setvalueforkey-in-nsmutabl)

Hi,

```
setObject:forKey:
```

Adds a given key-value pair to the dictionary.

```
- (void)setObject:(id)anObject forKey:(id)aKey
```

Again

```
setValue:forKey:
```

Adds a given key-value pair to the dictionary.

```
- (void)setValue:(id)value forKey:(NSString *)key
```

Then what is the difference in between them?
Is the difference only in receiving parameters?
can setObject:forKey: be used instead of setValue:forKey: ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249634/wheres-the-difference-between-setobjectforkey-and-setvalueforkey-in-nsmutabl) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062183/objective-c-whats-the-difference-between-objectforkey-and-valueforkey)

Answer (score 4):

From the doc:

[`setValue:forKey:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutabledictionary/1416335-setvalue?language=objc)

> Discussion
> This method adds value and key to the dictionary using setObject:forKey:, unless value is nil in which case the method instead attempts to remove key using removeObjectForKey:.

[`setObject:forKey:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutabledictionary/1411616-setobject?language=objc)

> Important
> Raises an NSInvalidArgumentException if aKey or anObject is nil. If you need to represent a nil value in the dictionary, use NSNull.

If aKey already exists in the dictionary, the dictionary’s previous value object for that key is sent a release message and anObject takes its place.