# Saving an object to array using NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios4, nsmutablearray, plist, nsmutabledictionary

I have been trying to add an object as an NSMutableDictionary to my array, which I am accessing from another view, and It doesn't seem to work. I want to be able to store the data in a plist which I access from a NSDictionary.

```
-(void)saveAlarm:(id)sender {

    // Adding object for alarm to AlarmViewController

    alarmArrayCopy = alarmViewController.alarmsTime;

    NSMutableDictionary *newAlarm =  [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [newAlarm setValue:labelTextField.text forKey:LABEL_KEY];
    [newAlarm setValue:alarmPicker.date forKey:TIME_KEY];
    [alarmArrayCopy addObject:(newAlarm)];

    // Dismissing and tiding up.

    [self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [newAlarm release];
}
```

**UPDATE: How do I add an NSDictionary to my plist database (my db is an array)?**

Here is some new code, I updated the NSMutableDictionary to NSDictionary because in my plist you can only have normal dictionaries not a mutable one. But now it crashed and gives me a `Thread 1:Program received signal: "SIGABRT".`

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"];

// Adding object for alarm to AlarmViewController

NSDictionary *newAlarm =  [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
[newAlarm setValue:labelTextField.text forKey:LABEL_KEY];
[newAlarm setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", alarmPicker.date] forKey:TIME_KEY];
[newAlarm writeToFile:finalPath atomically:NO];
```

or

-(IBAction)saveAlarm:(id)sender {

```
// Adding object for alarm to AlarmViewController

NSString *time = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", alarmPicker.date];
NSString *label = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",labelTextField.text];

NSDictionary *newAlarm = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:label, LABEL_KEY,time, TIME_KEY, nil];
self.alarmArrayCopy = alarmViewController.alarmsTime;
[alarmArrayCopy addObject:(newAlarm)];

// Dismissing and tiding up.
[newAlarm release];
[self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

}

Comment: I don't get any errors, it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should use `setObject:forKey:` method for adding objects to `NSMutableDictionary`. Second, you should use `initWithObjectsAndKeys:` method if you are using `NSDictionary`.

The `setValue:forKey` is a method of the *Key Value Coding* protocol. That was described at here “
[Where's the difference between setObject:forKey: and setValue:forKey: in NSMutableDictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249634/wheres-the-difference-between-setobjectforkey-and-setvalueforkey-in-nsmutab)
”

So, you should do that,

```
NSDictionary *newAlarm = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                               labelTextField.text, LABEL_KEY,
                                               alarmPicker.date, TIME_KEY, nil];
```

Comment: thanks, this solved my problem but I have encountered a new problem. The data stored in the dictionary, how do I add it to my plist? I mean I have tried writeToFile and trying to add it to a array but I can't. I will put some new code up.

Answer (score 1):

```
[newAlarm setValue:alarmPicker.date forKey:TIME_KEY];
```

I am not quite sure, but I guess your error is because you can't send an instance of NSDate object to setValue:forKey method. You may use either setObject:forKey or change NSDate to NSString by `[NSString stringWithFormat:"%@", alarmPicker.date]`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: `setObject:forKey`, not `setValue:forKey`