# What's the difference between setValue:forKey: and setObject:forKey: for NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.3

Just that--I'm a newbie and I don't know which one to use in any situation.

Comment: Dupcicle: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249634/wheres-the-difference-between-setobjectforkey-and-setvalueforkey-in-nsmutab

Answer (score 8):

There is no difference because neither exists for a `NSMutableArray`.

However, those methods exist for `NSMutableDictionary`.  The difference between the 2 is this:

From apple: [NSMutableDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsmutabledictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

**-setValue:forKey:**

> This method adds value and key to the dictionary using
>   setObject:forKey:, unless value is nil in which case the method
>   instead attempts to remove key using removeObjectForKey:.

Comment: Not sure what 'complete dupe' means.  The above is quoted (and cited) from apple's website.  Unless you intended to vote down the question.  Cheers.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I followed your link and it's not a duplicate of any of the answers there.