# Assigning values to keys in a mutable dictionary

Tags: ios, nsmutabledictionary

I have a function meant for an iOS app. The NSString `value`and `key` contain the value and key however it doesnt seem to get assign to the NSMutableDictionary `data` on the line `[data setValue:value forKey:key]`

```
-(NSMutableDictionary *)parseCode:(NSString *)string{
    NSArray *array = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"||"];
    NSMutableDictionary *data;
    for(id object in array){
        NSArray *objectAndKey = [object componentsSeparatedByString:@"::"];
        NSString *key =[objectAndKey objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *value = [objectAndKey objectAtIndex:1];
        [data setValue:value forKey:key];
        [self alertMeWithString:[data valueForKey:key]];
    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Beginner mistake.  Unlike most other languages, in Objective-C making a call on a nil pointer does not cause an error but simply returns zero/nil.

Comment: Related: [Where's the difference between setObject:forKey: and setValue:forKey: in NSMutableDictionary?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1249653/335858)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialise and allocate your NSMutableDictionary.

```
 NSMutableDictionary *data = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
```

Or you can explicitly make the calls using

```
 NSMutableDictionary *data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```