# NSLog always prints my key instead of my translation

Tags: objective-c, localization

I'm creating a NSError like this:

```
    NSMutableDictionary* details = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [details setValue:@"REQUEST_UNKNOWN_CONVERT_FOR_ENDPOINT" forKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey];
    NSError * error = [NSError errorWithDomain:DOMAIN code:200 userInfo:details];
```

where REQUEST_... is my key in my translation file (Localizable.strings).

when I get an error I try to print it like this:

```
  NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
```

It just prints my REQUEST_UNKNOWN...(my key) out instead of my translation.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How is it supposed to work then?  You expect `localizedDescription` to fetch a translation from file?

Comment: Yes I thought that this could be possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[details setObject:NSLocalizedString(@"REQUEST_UNKNOWN_CONVERT_FOR_ENDPOINT", Nil) forKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey];
```

You have to put value as localizedString, while you are adding it as standard NSString.

Comment: Here is the answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249634/wheres-the-difference-between-setobjectforkey-and-setvalueforkey-in-nsmutab