# set a C type value to NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Say, I have a **C** function:

```
const unsigned char *get_text(int idx);
```

In my **Swift** code, I invoke this **C** function:

```
let idx: CInt = 6
let txt = get_text(idx)
```

and I put the `txt` to a `NSMutableDictionary`:

```
var myDict = NSMutableDictionary()
//ERROR: Cannot invoke ‘setValue’ with an argument list of type ’UnsafePointer<UInt8>, forKey: String?)’
myDict.setValue(txt, forKey: “MyText”)
```

But I get the compiler error above. How can I set the value to my dictionary then?

Comment: Do you really need it to be a C string in the collection? If not you can use `[NSString stringWithCString:<(const char *)> encoding:<(NSStringEncoding)>];` and store the NSString version of the C string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C type `const unsigned char *` is mapped to Swift as
`UnsafePointer<UInt8>`. You can create an (optional) Swift string
from that pointer with

```
let str = String.fromCString(UnsafePointer(txt))
myDict.setValue(str, forKey: "MyText")
```

This assumes that the C string returned from `get_text()` is
UTF-8 encoded and NUL-terminated.

The `UnsafePointer()` conversion is necessary because `fromCString()`
takes an `UnsafePointer<CChar>` argument.
If you change the C function to

```
const char *get_text(int idx);
```

then it simplifies to

```
let str = String.fromCString(txt)
```

---

*Remark:* The proper method to set a value in `NSMutableDictionary`
is

```
setObject(_, forKey: _)
```

The Key-Value Coding method

```
setValue(_, forKey: _)
```

has the same effect in *most cases*. See for example
[Where's the difference between setObject:forKey: and setValue:forKey: in NSMutableDictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249634/wheres-the-difference-between-setobjectforkey-and-setvalueforkey-in-nsmutab)
for more information.

You could also consider to use a Swift `Dictionary` instead.